# Answer multiple questions from script shell

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, jenkins

I'm trying to run a **shell** script from command line section in a **Jenkins** job configuraton.

The issue here is to answer different questions from the same **.sh** **script** but the answers are different.

I cannot use '`yes o | myScript.sh`', because for the other questions the answers are '`1'` and '`2`' .

Looking for your hints and suggestions !

Comment: If the answer sequence is known in advance, why not hardcode it into the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the sequence of answers, use a shell [grouping construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping):

```
{ 
    echo answer1
    echo answer2
    echo answer3
    echo ...
} | myScript.sh
```